# Character pointer arrays

Tags: c++, string, pointers

omg im am so confused right now

what is wrong here and what can i do to fix it

**EDIT:** omg i am so sorry...i am just so fluctuated right now that i cant even ask a question

i want to assign 10 inputed char strings to a pointer array.

```
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *mess[10];
    int i = 0;

for (; i < 10; i++)
{                 
    cout << "Enter a string: ";   
    cin.getline(mess[i], 80);
}

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    cout << mess[i];

system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Did you include `<cstdlib>` for `system`?

Comment: Can you describe the problem you're having also?

Comment: You're asking what is wrong with this SO question? Where to begin...

Comment: -1 omg + you should ask a specific question. "Here I'm expecting this but getting this...here is where I've searched...this is what I've tried..."

Comment: omg i am so sorry. i just edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is probably declare your array this way:

```
char mess[10][80];
```

As you are reading up to 80 characters from getline.

Your current implementation builds an array of 10 `char*` which are never initialized to point on allocated buffers.

A much safer way would be to use `std::string` as the buffer size will be handled for you. A simple change to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string mess[10];
    int i = 0;

    for (; i < 10; i++)
    {                 
        cout << "Enter a string: ";   
        cin >> mess[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << mess[i] << endl; // you probably want to add endl here

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Should give you what you want.

**EDIT**

If you absolutely need `char *` (which is not a good idea), here's what you're looking for:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char* mess[10];
    int i = 0;

    for (; i < 10; i++)
    {                 
        cout << "Enter a string: ";   
        mess[i] = new char[80]; // allocate the memory
        cin.getline(mess[i], 80);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << mess[i] << endl;
        delete[] mess[i]; // deallocate the memory
    }

    // After deleting the memory, you should NOT access the element as they won't be pointing to valid memory

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: yea i know i can do that but i need to use a char pointer array

Comment: You're mixing C and C++ for no good reason here then... you will need to `new` and `delete` buffers to accommodate your strings

Comment: I just updated using the data you want

Answer (score 2):

You're allocating 10 pointers, but never intialize them to point to space where getline can read input to.

Comment: Correct. For a bonus point, recommend `std::string` and show how it's done

Answer (score 2):

You must first initialize the pointers you are declaring here `char *mess[10];` to allocate memory for them. You can do this by using the [new()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) expression to allocate the requested memory.

```
char *mess[10];
for (int k=0; k<10; k++)
{
    mess[k]=new char[80];
}
```

Remember that after allocating memory using the `new()` function you must always deallocate the memory used after you are done with the data. You can -**and you always should**- deallocate memory using the [delete()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) expression.

```
for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
{
   delete[] mess[j];
}
```

For more info about allocating/deallocating memory dynamically you can refer [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/).

Comment: Your solution is leaking memory

Comment: Your new'd arrays need to be delete[] after usage

Comment: @emartel: This is an incomplete snippet, and it doesn't show the end of the scope, where `mess` would no longer be reachable.  So how can you say there's a memory leak?

Comment: I have edited the answer to reflect the use of `delete()`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I believe that when teaching a new comer how to allocate memory, it is mandatory to explain how to deallocate it. Sure, in this very specific example the memory might be released by the OS, but it's not a good practice

Comment: @emartel To begin with using `new()` in that manner is not a good practice instead of using `vectors` :)

Comment: @Aposperite you're not `new`ing the array, just the `string`s, so your analogy isn't quite right :) In this case, I believe the static array still has its place, but using `std::string` is way more elegant than `new` and `delete` `char*`! :) I will +1, seems to be what the OP is looking for

Comment: You've got a bit of mixed up terminology here.  What you're using is the the [new expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new), and the [delete expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete), but you've linked to (and called it) [operator new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new), which is a raw memory allocation function (it doesn't create objects) that is invoked by the new expression (which allocates memory *and* creates objects).